# Como listar dados do mysqli exibindo em DESC mas listando de cima pra baixo?

Tags: php, mysqli

Vou tentar explicar melhor, tipo assim, ao listar algo do banco com id DESC mostra algo assim:

```
id:1
id:2
id:3
id:4
id:5
```

mas eu quero que seja exibido assim:

```
id:5
id:4
id:3
id:2
id:1
```

Nesse caso usar ORDER BY id ASC não vai me ajudar porque preciso listar varios dados e com isso, os ultimos id's não vão aparecer caso eu dê um LIMIT!.

Para quem quiser ver um pedaço do codigo:

```
public function quadroAlunos($id){
    $this->Query = $this->Conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM quadroAlun ORDER BY ? DESC");
    $this->Query->bind_param("s",$id);
    $this->Query->execute();
    $this->ResultadoUser = $this->Query->get_result();
    while($this->Listar = $this->ResultadoUser->fetch_assoc()):

    echo "<strong class=aluno>".$this->Listar["nick"].":</strong>"; //Recupera nick
    echo "<span class=mensagem>".$this->Listar["mensagem"]."</span>"; //Recupera Mensagem
    echo "<span class=hora>".$this->Listar["data"]."</span>"; //Recupera hora da postagem
    echo "<br /><br />"; //Quebra de linhas

    endwhile;
}
```

Comment: Seria bom [edit] a pergunta e por o trecho relevante do código para analisarmos. Explique o resultado que quer obter, que fica mais fácil. E com DESC o resultado não pode ser o que você afirmou, tem coisa errada aí.

Comment: Pronto, editei!

Comment: Tem um problema no seu código, você está passando um valor onde deveria ser um nome de coluna. Com essa ? aí não vai funcionar nunca o ORDER. Você está ordenando com um valor fixo. (o ID passado será sempre o mesmo)

Comment: Tipo assim, os dados estão sendo listados de baixo pra cima, sendo que os de baixo são os ultimos id's e os de cima os primeiros id's, esta listando tipo um chat, o chat você sabe que lista as ultimas mensagens de baixo pra cima, sendo as de baixo as novas mensagens e as de cima as antigas entendeu ? eu quero inverter isso

Comment: Estão de baixo pra cima pq esse order aí está completamente sem sentido. Você tem que por o nome da coluna no order, e não passar um valor pra ela. Esse binding aí não funciona como você está imaginando. Ponha ORDER BY id DESC que funciona (e tire esse binding daí, que não está te ajudando em nada).

Comment: deu certo mesmo, vlw, teve uma vez que precisei que listasse igual esta listando agora e não consegui kkkk

Comment: Se precisar mudar a coluna que está ordenando, precisa fazer com strings `"SELECT * FROM quadroAlun ORDER BY $coluna"` - mas tem que tomar cuidado pra não permitir injeção de SQL em $coluna. Ai poderia chamar `quadroAlunos('nome')`, por exemplo, se quiser por nome, e `quadroAlunos('id DESC')` por id e invertido. Mas antes de complicar, termine de fazer funcionar por ID direitinho, pra não fazer confusão.

Answer (score 1):

Assim como o [Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco) já te explicou, você está utilizando o [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) de maneira incorreta. Esse método passa uma variável para o comando `SQL` previamente definido. Se você "printar" tua query com método [`debugDumpParams`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php), verá que sua query está sendo montada incorretamente, exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM quadroAlun ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Note que deveria ser `ORDER BY id DESC`, porém como você está passando o valor da variável `$id` via `bind_param`, ela foi substituída no comando `SQL`.

Se esse seu método `quadroAlunos` for apenas para lisar TODOS os alunos, o parâmetro `id` declarado na função é inútil e não tem serventia alguma. Aconselho a revisar o que está tentando implementar.

Dessa forma, seu código ficará algo como:

```
$this->Query = $this->Conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM quadroAlun ORDER BY id DESC");
$this->Query->execute();
$this->ResultadoUser = $this->Query->get_result();
```